# Remove the Disqus vote up

Tags: javascript, disqus

I am using the disqus 2012. I already have a rating system implemented on my site so wish to remove the star in the top right corner of the comments as it's just a bit confusing. When I hover over it says 'vote up'. is there anyway to remove this from my comments?

Answer (score 2):

Starring has a pretty important function so users can "favorite" or "like" a discussion and share it with users who are following them, so it can't be removed.

The hover state should also now say *Star this discussion* to be more explicit that this exists for the comment thread only. Hopefully that alleviates any worry of confusing users.